# phantomjs not closing and leaving orphan processes

Tags: memory-leaks, webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

On PhantomJS 1.9.2, ubuntu 12 LTS and Ghostdirver 1.04 together with selenium 2.35 I get dangling phantomjs processes after my tests. Anyone knows a good way how to fix this?

Here is a test program that demonstrates the odd behavior:

```
package testing;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class PhantomIsNotKilledDemo {

    private static WebDriver getDriver(){
        String browserPathStr = System.getProperty("selenium.pathToBrowser");
        if (browserPathStr == null) browserPathStr = "/home/user1/apps/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs";

        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();

        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        caps.setCapability(
                PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                browserPathStr );

        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

        return driver;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            WebDriver d1 = getDriver();
            d1.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951264");

            System.out.println("done with cycle " + (i+1) +" of "+max);
            d1.close();
            //d1.quit();
        }

        System.out.println("done");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

To run this, you should supply the path of your phantomjs binary as system property or set the variable accordingly.

After letting this run I do this shell command

```
ps -ef | grep phantomjs
```

and find 10 dangling phantomjs processes.

If I use `d1.quit()` instead, I end up with no dangling process. This is clearly better, but still I would have expected to get the same result with `.close`.

**Note, this is a crosspost of**
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/162#issuecomment-25536311

**Update** This post is changed according to Richard's suggestion (see below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `quit()` to terminate the process instead of `close()`.

As you have discovered, close will close the current window (and browser), but it will not shut down the process. This is useful for if you are going to send additional commands to the process or want to inspect the process.

Quit is for when you want to close every window and stop the process, which sounds like what you are looking for.

The [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) for these two methods reads:

> **close()**
>
> Close the current window, quitting the browser if it's the
> last window currently open.
>
> **quit()**
>
> Quits this driver, closing every associated window.

Comment: finally someone sheds some light on this. Maybe they clarified the docs since I asked my question since back then I did not see the difference. It is still a pretty strange and rather unexpected behavior, but oh well - so be it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rewrite your code to something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        WebDriver d1 = getDriver();

        d1.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951264");

        System.out.println("done with cycle " + (i+1) +" of "+max);
        d1.quit();
    }

    System.out.println("done");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why the `.close()` is not ending the WebDriver.  In theory, `.close()` should quit WebDriver if it is called on the last open window.  Perhaps something is opening a second window when that url is called?  Or maybe `.close()` works differently for phantomjs.

As to why `.quit()` isn't closing all of the phantomjs sessions, the last `getDriver()` you're calling does not have a corresponding `.quit()` outside of the loop.  I restructured your for loop to create the instance of WebDriver, perform your test, then `.quit()` that session of WebDriver/phantomjs at the end of each loop.

Comment: you are right about the wrong placement of ```WebDriver d1 = getDriver();``` I change my question. thx for pointing that out. However, the real question is why ```.close()``` is not doing what it should do. There is only one window really. You can take other urls and have the same effect.